# Neural network from scratch: only predicts training inputs correctly

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

Here is a neural network I've been working on. It takes in an array of four zeros or ones and predicts whether that pattern of zeros and ones is a backslash.

```
import numpy as np

class NeuralNetwork():

    correct = 0
    num_predictions = 10
    epochs = 5000
    learningRate = 0.1

    def __init__(self, sizes, sizeOfEpoch):
        self.sizeOfEpoch = sizeOfEpoch 
        self.dimensions = sizes

        self.secondLayerNeurons = np.empty(sizes[1])
        self.outputNeurons = np.empty(sizes[2])

        self.firstLayerWeights = np.random.rand(sizes[1], sizes[0])
        self.secondLayerWeights = np.random.rand(sizes[2], sizes[1])
        self.firstLayerBiases = np.random.rand(sizes[1])
        self.secondLayerBiases = np.random.rand(sizes[2])

        self.firstLayerWeightsSummations = np.zeros([sizes[1], sizes[0]])
        self.secondLayerWeightsSummations = np.zeros([sizes[2], sizes[1]])
        self.firstLayerBiasesSummations = np.zeros([sizes[1]])
        self.secondLayerBiasesSummations = np.zeros([sizes[2]])

        self.hiddenLayerErrors = np.empty(sizes[1])
        self.outputLayerErrors = np.empty(sizes[2])

    def sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

    def sigmoidDerivative(self, x):
        return np.multiply(x,(1-x))

    def forwardProp(self, inputs):
        for i in range (self.dimensions[1]):
            self.secondLayerNeurons[i] = self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.firstLayerWeights[i], inputs)+self.firstLayerBiases[i])
        for i in range (self.dimensions[2]):
            self.outputNeurons[i] = self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.secondLayerWeights[i], self.secondLayerNeurons)+self.secondLayerBiases[i])

    def backProp(self, inputs, correct_output):
        self.outputLayerErrors = np.subtract(self.outputNeurons, correct_output)
        self.hiddenLayerErrors = np.multiply(np.dot(self.secondLayerWeights.T, self.outputLayerErrors), self.sigmoidDerivative(self.secondLayerNeurons))

        for i in range (self.dimensions[2]):
            for j in range (self.dimensions[1]):
                if j==0:
                    self.secondLayerBiasesSummations[i] += self.outputLayerErrors[i]
                self.secondLayerWeightsSummations[i][j] += self.outputLayerErrors[i]*self.secondLayerNeurons[j]
        for i in range (self.dimensions[1]):
            for j in range (self.dimensions[0]):
                if j==0:
                    self.firstLayerBiasesSummations[i] += self.hiddenLayerErrors[i]
                self.firstLayerWeightsSummations[i][j] += self.hiddenLayerErrors[i]*inputs[j]

    def train(self, trainImages, trainLabels):
        size = str(self.sizeOfEpoch)

        for m in range (self.sizeOfEpoch):
            correct_output = trainLabels[m]

            self.forwardProp(trainImages[m].flatten())
            self.backProp(trainImages[m].flatten(), correct_output)

            if self.outputNeurons > 0.90 and trainLabels[m] == 1 or self.outputNeurons < 0.1 and trainLabels[m] == 0:
                self.correct+=1
            accuracy = str(int((self.correct/(m+1))*100)) + '%'
            percent = str(int((m/self.sizeOfEpoch)*100)) + '%'
            print ("Progress: " + percent + " -- Accuracy: " + accuracy, end="\r")
        self.change()
        self.correct = 0

        print (size+'/'+size+" -- Accuracy: "+accuracy+" -- Error: "+str(np.amax(np.absolute(self.outputLayerErrors))),end="\r")

    def change(self):
        self.secondLayerBiases -= self.learningRate*self.secondLayerBiasesSummations
        self.firstLayerBiases -= self.learningRate*self.firstLayerBiasesSummations
        self.secondLayerWeights -= self.learningRate*self.secondLayerWeightsSummations
        self.firstLayerWeights -= self.learningRate*self.firstLayerWeightsSummations
        self.firstLayerSummations = np.zeros([self.dimensions[1], self.dimensions[0]])
        self.secondLayerSummations = np.zeros([self.dimensions[2], self.dimensions[1]])
        self.firstLayerBiasesSummations = np.zeros(self.dimensions[1])
        self.secondLayerBiasesSummations = np.zeros(self.dimensions[2])
            
    def predict(self, testImage):
        secondLayerAnsNodes = np.empty([self.dimensions[1]])
        outputAns = np.empty([self.dimensions[2]])
        for i in range (self.dimensions[1]):
            secondLayerAnsNodes[i] = self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.firstLayerWeights[i], testImage)+self.firstLayerBiases[i])
        for i in range (self.dimensions[2]):
            outputAns[i] = self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.secondLayerWeights[i], secondLayerAnsNodes)+self.secondLayerBiases[i])
        return outputAns

if __name__ == "__main__":
    train_images = np.array([[1,0,0,1],[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0]])
    train_labels = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0])

    neural_network = NeuralNetwork([4, 2, 1], train_images.shape[0])

    for i in range (neural_network.epochs):
        print ("\nEpoch", str(i+1) + "/" + str(neural_network.epochs))
        neural_network.train(train_images, train_labels)

    for i in range (neural_network.num_predictions):
        print("\n\n\nNew Situations: " + str(i+1) + "/" + str(neural_network.num_predictions))
        A = list(map(int,input("Enter the numbers : ").strip().split()))[:4] 

        try:
            result = neural_network.predict(A)
        except ValueError:
            print("\nValueError, try again")
            continue

        print("\nOutput Data:", result[0])
        if result>0.95:
            print("Result: Back Slash")
        else:
            print("Result: Not Back Slash")
```

This program only predicts the training examples correctly. When I give it [0,0,0,1] or [1,0,0,0] it predicts that it is a backslash. Also, I have run the classic xor problem with this exact code (just change the dimensions of the NN and also the training I/O) and it works perfectly. I have also made a logistic regression program almost identical to this one except it doesn't have a hidden layer. For the logistic regression program, all inputs are predicted correctly.

How do I fix/change this NN so that it can correctly predict inputs it hasn't seen before?

Comment: Did you try to add more training images?

Comment: If the code is working fine, then perhaps this question is better suited to one of these stack exchange sites? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms

Comment: @Multihunter Which site would you recommend for this question?

Comment: My guess is that what you are are seeing is due to the statistics involved (you have a large class imbalance in your training set, for example). And CrossValidated is the biggest, so I think that would be the best one.

Comment: @Multihunter I kinda thought about what you mentioned but why would it work with logistic regression but not a neural network? Btw, just tried posting on CrossValidated, I just copied and pasted but it says only one post per 40 mins, so I guess I'll have to wait.

Comment: Neural networks can represent more complicated functions, and more complicated functions can match your training set well (especially because it's so small) while being utterly wrong. This is generally called "overffitting". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting

Comment: @Multihunter Thanks for the advice, but I already tried adding a regularization term and it hasn't helped, could there be any other problems?

Comment: Sure there could be other problems. This problem is going to take a while to understand and fix, which I'm not going to do (sorry). If I were you, I would write unit tests for the back propagation. Then, track validation performance while training (just forward pass on validation during training loop). You have a very limited search space, so I would want to know what the model gave for each of the possible outputs. Can you solve it manually and check if the weights make sense? fyi overfitting is a symptom of many causes, and regularisation isn't guaranteed to fix it.

Comment: @Multihunter I print out my accuracy and my error and at the end the accuracy is 100%, meaning that all training examples per epoch are predicted correctly. The error eventually gets so small that its just 0. The outputs it gives are extremely close to zero and one for everything except [0,0,0,1] and [1,0,0,0]. For those, it gives the exact same output as [1,0,0,1]. What would be examples of ways to fix overfitting? Thanks for the comments btw!

Comment: You can and should evaluate validation set accuracy during training. Sometimes people just shrug and just stop training if validation set performance starts dropping https://machinelearningmastery.com/early-stopping-to-avoid-overtraining-neural-network-models/ But since this is a toy example, you probably don't care about that. CrossValidated will hopefully assist with your understanding why a "perfect solution" for the training set doesn't imply generalisation performance.

Comment: @Multihunter Hmmm, interesting, thanks a lot for the help, hopefully i'll start getting answers/comments on CrossValidated!